# Optimizing TCHart drawing in Delphi 7

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, teechart

My [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4767684/large-tchart-takes-a-long-time-to-draw) had some great input, but it didn't work for me because my problem seems to be Delphi 7 related.

I have a chart with a single series (TFastLineSeries) and 3,600 datapoints which is taking up to 45 seconds to draw. Others have said that it should be lightning fast, so who can help, bearing in mind that I am using Delphi 7 and the standard TChart component.

I suspect that instead of calling AddXY() 3,600 times I should be preparing the data first, then adding it all at once.

---

Update:  in D7 the AddXy() function signature is `function AddXY(Const AXValue, AYValue: Double; Const AXLabel: String; AColor: TColor) : Longint; where`timeLabel`is a string representing MM:SS. But what value should I be passing for`

and I cam calling it with `Chart1.Series[0].AddXY(Chart1.Series[0].Count, codValue, timeLabel, clRed

---

btw, I have coded      Chart1.Series[0].XValues.DateTime := True;
   Chart1.BottomAxis.DateTimeFormat := 'nn:ss';  //'hh' or 'nn' or 'ss' as you wish, e.g. Chart1.BottomAxis.DateTimeFormat:="dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm";

Comment: what happens when you prepare it and add it all at once?

Comment: If it will do what you want it to do, the TJvChart in JVCL is also much faster at drawing than TChart is, for line series.  You can add 3600 items, and plot once, which is guaranteed to be faster than having it update lots of times,but then I'm sure it's possible to do that in TChart too.

Comment: +1 David, that is what I would like to do, but am not sure how to code it

Comment: +1 Warren, I would prefer to stick to TChart. Others have stated that it should be no problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe the way you are generating the values to put in the chart is the bottleneck?

On Delphi 2010, I measured the following code to take less than 1/10 second:

```
var
  I: Integer;
begin
  for I := 0 to 3000 - 1 do
    Series1.AddXY(Random(1000), Random(100));
```

Comment: +1 Thanks for the feedabck. The Y -axis is a real (perhaps I should round it and convert to double? In RL it will always be 0 to 2,000 and I doubt that anyone would visually notice the decimal parts on a chart).  The X-axis is a string (a time label in the format MM:SS, so maybe that is it). I will check it & get back to you.  Hmm, maybe it's autoscaling? Wouldn't that have to be calculated at every AddXY() ?

Comment: Also, in D7, the function is function AddXY(Const AXValue, AYValue: Double; Const AXLabel: String; AColor: TColor) : Longint;   and I am passing  Chart1.Series[0].Count as the first param.I guess that takes time to calculate too ... or does it? Surely it's just incremented by every call to AddXY ?

Comment: +1 I give the answer because you have helped me see how to express my question correctly

Comment: Real? Isn't that really slow? Why on earth use Real? You should be using Double.

Answer (score 1):

Btw: It can also speed up the drawing to set Chart1.AutoRepaint to false before you add your values and set if back to true afterwards

Answer (score 1):

This may help you from the developer of TeeChart....
[Fast line drawing with TeeChart](http://www.delphigroups.info/2/7/359178.html)